# How To Make scroll work correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

```
$(document).scroll(function(e) {   
    if($(document).scrollTop() >=300) {
       $(document).scrollTop(0);
    }
});
```

please can you advise how i can put a return false/ return true or bind/unbind this function.

This works when my popup is open however when the popup is closed the entire website max scroll bar height remains 300 and i want it to reset back to working fully.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I added

```
$(window).unbind('scroll');
```

in the **close** button.